# How to detect culture info of a text

Tags: c#

I want to create a game which the user saves some words and meanings in an array of strings.

[image: see this image]

Then the program makes a quiz for the user and shows the word and the user should guess the meaning that he recently saved.

[image: see this image]

I don't know in which language the meanings are saved. I want to detect the meanings characters and automatically change input language of the quiz textbox to the meanings language so the user does not have to change it manually.

example:
First time: the word is

> Hi

and the user should type

> سلام (in arabic)(The input language should be arabic)

Second time: the word is

> Hello

and the user shoud type

> Tjena (in swedish)(The input language should be swedish)

```
 Application.CurrentInputLanguage = 
        InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("Detected languages culturifo"));
```

There is a way of detecting characters via Regex:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(theMeaningString, @"\p{IsArabic}")){
Application.CurrentInputLanguage = 
    InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ar-EG")); 
}
```

But as there are lots of keyboard input languages it's hard to check all of them. Is there anyway to detect culture info with Regex?

Comment: There are APIs that can help with this - e.g. the [Azure Text Translate API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) (which has a free tier) has a [language detection](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/get_Detect) endpoint.

Comment: There is no built-in method to CultureInfo for this. You will have to create your own method and return the detected CultureInfo from it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem with Azure is that it requires internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do it the hard way. So I created a method that Tries to get a list of culture names that matches a strings characters. It might sometimes get wrong list as some languages share characters. But it is good enough for my purpose. Then I compare the list with installed keyboard layout. If a culture info in the list matches the installed keyboard layouts then it is the culture info of the text, because the user who typed it used the installed keyboard layout.
Comment if you have a better idea!

```
   private CultureInfo GetMatchingCultureInfo(string theString)
    {

        List<string> arrayOfCultureNames = new List<string>();

        if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsBasicLatin}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //English
            //French
            //Spanish
            //German
            //Swedish
            //Vietnamese 

            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sv-FI"); //   Swedish - Finland    0x081D  SVF
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sv-SE"); //   Swedish - Sweden 0x041D 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-BE");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-CA");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-FR");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-LU");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-MC");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fr-CH");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("de-AT");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("de-DE");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("de-LI");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("de-LU");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("de-CH");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-AR"); //   Spanish - Argentina  0x2C0A  ESS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-BO"); //   Spanish - Bolivia    0x400A  ESB
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CL"); //   Spanish - Chile  0x340A  ESL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CO"); //   Spanish - Colombia   0x240A  ESO
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CR"); //   Spanish - Costa Rica 0x140A  ESC
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-DO"); //   Spanish - Dominican Republic 0x1C0A  ESD
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-EC"); //   Spanish - Ecuador    0x300A  ESF
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-SV"); //   Spanish - El Salvador    0x440A  ESE
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-GT"); //   Spanish - Guatemala  0x100A  ESG
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-HN"); //   Spanish - Honduras   0x480A  ESH
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-MX"); //   Spanish - Mexico 0x080A  ESM
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-NI"); //   Spanish - Nicaragua  0x4C0A  ESI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PA"); //   Spanish - Panama 0x180A  ESA
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PY"); //   Spanish - Paraguay   0x3C0A  ESZ
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PE"); //   Spanish - Peru   0x280A  ESR
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PR"); //   Spanish - Puerto Rico    0x500A  ES
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-ES"); //   Spanish - Spain  0x0C0A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-UY"); //   Spanish - Uruguay    0x380A  ESY
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-VE"); //   Spanish - Venezuela  0x200A  ESV  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("vi-VN");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("nl-BE");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-AU");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-CA");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-CB");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-IE");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-JM");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-NZ");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-PH");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-ZA");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-TT");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-GB");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-US");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("en-ZW"); 
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsLatinExtended-A}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Latin
            //Czech
            //Dutch
            //Polish
            //Turkish
            //Lithuanian
            //Latvian   
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("cs-CZ"); //   Czech - Czech Republic    0x0405  CSY  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("nl-BE"); //   Dutch
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hu-HU"); //   Hungarian - Hungary  0x040E  HUN  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("lv-LV"); //   Latvian - Latvia 0x0426  LVI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("lt-LT"); //   Lithuanian - Lithuania   0x0427  LTH 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pl-PL"); //   Polish - Poland  0x0415  PLK    
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("tr-TR"); //   Turkish - Turkey 0x041F  TRK  
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsLatinExtended-B}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            // Africa alphabet
            //Pan - Nigerian
            //Americanist
            //Khoisan
            //Pinyin
            //Romanian
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("af-ZA");    //  Afrikaans - South Africa   0x0436  AFK    
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ro-RO"); //   Romanian - Romania   0x0418  ROM  
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsGreek}") || Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsGreekandCoptic}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Greek 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("el-GR");  
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsCyrillic}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets: 
            // Belarus
            // Bosnia and Herzegovina(mostly in Serb inhabited parts of the country))
            //Bulgaria
            //Kazakhstan
            //Kyrgyzstan
            //Macedonia
            //Mongolia(also Mongolian Script)
            //Montenegro(also Latin)
            //Russia
            //Serbia(also Latin)
            //Tajikistan
            //Ukraine   
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("be-BY"); //   Belarusian - Belarus  0x0423  BEL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("bg-BG"); //   Bulgarian - Bulgaria  0x0402  BGR   
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kk-KZ"); //   Kazakh - Kazakhstan  0x043F 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ky-KZ"); //   Kyrgyz - Kazakhstan  0x0440 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mk-MK"); //   Macedonian (FYROM)   0x042F  MKD  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mn-MN"); //   Mongolian - Mongolia 0x0450  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ru-RU"); //   Russian - Russia 0x0419  RUS 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Cy-sr-SP"); //   Serbian (Cyrillic) - Serbia   0x0C1A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Lt-sr-SP"); //   Serbian (Latin) - Serbia  0x081A    
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("tt-RU"); //   Tatar - Russia   0x0444 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("uk-UA"); //   Ukrainian - Ukraine  0x0422  UKR  
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsArmenian}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Armenian 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hy-AM"); //   Armenian - Armenia    0x042B   
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsHebrew}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Hebrew   
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("he-IL"); //   Hebrew - Israel  0x040D  HEB   
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsArabic}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Arabic
            //Persian 

            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("fa-IR");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-DZ"); //  Arabic - Algeria  0x1401  ARG
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-BH"); //   Arabic - Bahrain  0x3C01  ARH
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-EG"); //   Arabic - Egypt    0x0C01  ARE
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-IQ"); //   Arabic - Iraq 0x0801  ARI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-JO"); //   Arabic - Jordan   0x2C01  ARJ
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-KW"); //   Arabic - Kuwait   0x3401  ARK
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-LB"); //   Arabic - Lebanon  0x3001  ARB
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-LY"); //   Arabic - Libya    0x1001  ARL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-MA"); //   Arabic - Morocco  0x1801  ARM
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-OM"); //   Arabic - Oman 0x2001  ARO
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-QA"); //   Arabic - Qatar    0x4001  ARQ
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-SA"); //   Arabic - Saudi Arabia 0x0401  ARA
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-SY"); //   Arabic - Syria    0x2801  ARS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-TN"); //   Arabic - Tunisia  0x1C01  ART
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-AE"); //   Arabic - United Arab Emirates 0x3801  ARU
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ar-YE"); //   Arabic - Yemen    0x2401  ARY 
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsSyriac}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //Syriac 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("syr-SY"); //   Syriac - Syria  0x045A 
        }

        else if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"\p{IsDevanagari}"))
        {
            // Major alphabets:
            //India and Nepal 

            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("gu-IN"); 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hi-IN"); //   Hindi - India    0x0439  HIN 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kn-IN"); //   Kannada - India  0x044B 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kok-IN"); //   Konkani - India 0x0457 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mr-IN"); //   Marathi - India  0x044E 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pa-IN"); //   Punjabi - India  0x0446 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sa-IN"); //   Sanskrit - India 0x044F  
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ta-IN"); //   Tamil - India    0x0449 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("te-IN"); //   Telugu - India   0x044A 
        }

        else 
        {
            // Major alphabets:   
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Cy-az-AZ"); //   Azeri(Cyrillic) - Azerbaijan  0x082C
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Lt-az-AZ");  //  Azeri(Latin) - Azerbaijan 0x042C
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("eu-ES"); //   Basque - Basque   0x042D  EUQ
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("be-BY"); //   Belarusian - Belarus  0x0423  BEL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("bg-BG"); //   Bulgarian - Bulgaria  0x0402  BGR
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ca-ES"); //   Catalan - Catalan 0x0403  CAT
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-CN"); //   Chinese - China   0x0804  CHS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-HK"); //   Chinese - Hong Kong SAR   0x0C04  ZHH
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-MO"); //   Chinese - Macau SAR   0x1404
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-SG"); //   Chinese - Singapore   0x1004  ZHI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-TW"); //   Chinese - Taiwan  0x0404  CHT
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-CHS"); //   Chinese(Simplified) 0x0004
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("zh-CHT"); //   Chinese(Traditional)    0x7C04
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hr-HR"); //   Croatian - Croatia    0x041A  HRV
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("cs-CZ"); //   Czech - Czech Republic    0x0405  CSY
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("da-DK"); //   Danish - Denmark  0x0406  DAN
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("div-MV"); //   Dhivehi - Maldives   0x0465 
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("he-IL"); //   Hebrew - Israel  0x040D  HEB
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hi-IN"); //   Hindi - India    0x0439  HIN
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("hu-HU"); //   Hungarian - Hungary  0x040E  HUN
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("is-IS");  //  Icelandic - Iceland  0x040F  ISL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("id-ID"); //   Indonesian - Indonesia   0x0421
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("it-IT"); //   Italian - Italy  0x0410
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("it-CH"); //   Italian - Switzerland    0x0810  ITS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ja-JP"); //   Japanese - Japan 0x0411  JPN
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kn-IN"); //   Kannada - India  0x044B
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kk-KZ"); //   Kazakh - Kazakhstan  0x043F
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("kok-IN"); //   Konkani - India 0x0457
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ko-KR"); //   Korean - Korea   0x0412  KOR
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ky-KZ"); //   Kyrgyz - Kazakhstan  0x0440
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("lv-LV"); //   Latvian - Latvia 0x0426  LVI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("lt-LT"); //   Lithuanian - Lithuania   0x0427  LTH
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mk-MK"); //   Macedonian (FYROM)   0x042F  MKD
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ms-BN"); //   Malay - Brunei   0x083E
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ms-MY"); //   Malay - Malaysia 0x043E
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mr-IN"); //   Marathi - India  0x044E
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("mn-MN"); //   Mongolian - Mongolia 0x0450
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("nb-NO"); //   Norwegian (Bokmål) - Norway  0x0414
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("nn-NO"); //   Norwegian (Nynorsk) - Norway 0x0814
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pl-PL"); //   Polish - Poland  0x0415  PLK
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pt-BR"); //   Portuguese - Brazil  0x0416  PTB
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pt-PT"); //   Portuguese - Portugal    0x0816
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("pa-IN"); //   Punjabi - India  0x0446
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ro-RO"); //   Romanian - Romania   0x0418  ROM
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ru-RU"); //   Russian - Russia 0x0419  RUS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sa-IN"); //   Sanskrit - India 0x044F
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Cy-sr-SP"); //   Serbian (Cyrillic) - Serbia   0x0C1A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Lt-sr-SP"); //   Serbian (Latin) - Serbia  0x081A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sk-SK"); //   Slovak - Slovakia    0x041B  SKY
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sl-SI"); //   Slovenian - Slovenia 0x0424  SLV
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-AR"); //   Spanish - Argentina  0x2C0A  ESS
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-BO"); //   Spanish - Bolivia    0x400A  ESB
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CL"); //   Spanish - Chile  0x340A  ESL
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CO"); //   Spanish - Colombia   0x240A  ESO
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-CR"); //   Spanish - Costa Rica 0x140A  ESC
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-DO"); //   Spanish - Dominican Republic 0x1C0A  ESD
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-EC"); //   Spanish - Ecuador    0x300A  ESF
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-SV"); //   Spanish - El Salvador    0x440A  ESE
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-GT"); //   Spanish - Guatemala  0x100A  ESG
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-HN"); //   Spanish - Honduras   0x480A  ESH
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-MX"); //   Spanish - Mexico 0x080A  ESM
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-NI"); //   Spanish - Nicaragua  0x4C0A  ESI
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PA"); //   Spanish - Panama 0x180A  ESA
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PY"); //   Spanish - Paraguay   0x3C0A  ESZ
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PE"); //   Spanish - Peru   0x280A  ESR
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-PR"); //   Spanish - Puerto Rico    0x500A  ES
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-ES"); //   Spanish - Spain  0x0C0A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-UY"); //   Spanish - Uruguay    0x380A  ESY
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("es-VE"); //   Spanish - Venezuela  0x200A  ESV
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("sw-KE");  //   Swahili - Kenya 0x0441
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("syr-SY"); //   Syriac - Syria  0x045A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ta-IN"); //   Tamil - India    0x0449
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("tt-RU"); //   Tatar - Russia   0x0444
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("te-IN"); //   Telugu - India   0x044A
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("th-TH"); //   Thai - Thailand  0x041E  THA
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("tr-TR"); //   Turkish - Turkey 0x041F  TRK
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("uk-UA"); //   Ukrainian - Ukraine  0x0422  UKR
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("ur-PK");  //  Urdu - Pakistan  0x0420  URD
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Cy-uz-UZ");
            arrayOfCultureNames.Add("Lt-uz-UZ"); 
        }


        // Get installed keyboard layouts and compare them with our culture list. If there is an installed keyboard layout for 
        // one of the culture names in our list then return that culture info.
        CultureInfo[] InstalledKeyboardLayouts = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.InstalledWin32Cultures);
        InputLanguage il;
        string cultureName;

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfCultureNames.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (CultureInfo ci in InstalledKeyboardLayouts)
            {
                il = InputLanguage.FromCulture(ci);
                if (il != null)
                {
                     cultureName = il.Culture.ToString();

                     if (arrayOfCultureNames[i].Contains(cultureName))
                    {
                        return new CultureInfo(cultureName);
                     }
                }

            }

        }

        //If the culture info is not detected then return the first culture info (the first installed keyboard layout)

        il = InputLanguage.FromCulture(InstalledKeyboardLayouts[0]);
        if (il != null)
        {
            return (new CultureInfo(il.Culture.ToString()));
        }

        //If non of above works then return null
        return null;
    }
```

Then when i get the culture info i can change the keyboard layout:

```
CultureInfo cf = GetMatchingCultureInfo(theMeaningString);
            if (cf != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(cf);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A text file does not save any culture information. It seems you are conflating *encoding* and *language*.

If you need to save language information in a particular text file consider using a header *your application understands* that specifies the language of everything that follows:

```
[English] //specifies the language is english
....
```

And another file would be:

```
[Swedish]
.....
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is a way of detecting characters via Regex:
if(Regex.IsMatch(theMeaningString, @"\p{IsArabic}")){
Application.CurrentInputLanguage = 
    InputLanguage.FromCulture(new CultureInfo("ar-EG")); 
}


But as there are lots of keyboard input languages it's hard to check all of them. Is there anyway to detect culture info with Regex?

Comment: @BenjaminRonneling Arabic is easy because they don't have the Latin alphabet, but many languages share a common alphabet (English, french, German) except for a few exceptions like ö etc.

It is impossible to detect that in every word, e.g. the German hallo doesn't have it.

Also, some words (e.g. entrepreneur) exist in multiple languages, thus making it almost impossible to determine the language of a single word.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Josef.